# Texturing drawn shapes - python pygame

Tags: python, pygame, textures, transparency, mask

Im currently using the random import to create five random x, y values and taking those values and drawing a polygon with the pygame.draw.polygon () command. If I had a texture square I wanted to apply over top of that shape instead of having just on rgb value what would be the most efficient way to do that? i want to take the generated polygon below and with out hard coding its shape, taking a general texture square and making all that green that new texture as if that shape was cut out of the texture square.

```
import pygame,random
from pygame import*

height = 480
width = 640
#colors

red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

pygame.init()


points = [ ]

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("PlayBox")

r = random

for i in range(0,5):
    x = r.randrange(0,640)
    y = r.randrange(0,480)
    points.append([x,y])

running = True
while running == True:
    screen.fill(white)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            break

    pygame.draw.polygon(screen,green,points,0)
    pygame.display.update()      
pygame.display.update()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the desired output actually?

Comment: To take a png picture or texture and apply it overtop of the shape while still retaining the same shape

Comment: Not sure what edit text shape means but let me try to reexplain im getting 5 points and making a polygon so the shape with change with every run of the program atm when using the pygame.draw.polygon command you can only use rgb values is there a way I can take that shape I just drew and texture a png over top of only the shape like if the png is a square and the shape if circle it makes a texture only inside the circle

Comment: This is better. Now this is a polygon, you don't want to use rgb right

Comment: i want to take a texture like grass for example and only texture that polygon not the white background

Comment: I understand now correctly (`Finally`) :-)

Comment: I'm working on this since you edit your question, probably http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html this one will help you

Comment: Pixel arrays seem to take rgb values

Comment: As a side comment: your code above will have pygame drawing polygons and flikering at the top speed in the machine it is running: it will always use 100% CPU and have completly different results depending on the target machinne speed. For a better result, consider adding a programed delay just after you display.update - a call to pygame.time.delay(30) for example, will add a wait of 30ms between each frame.

Comment: Just a example not all of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, of course, would be to re-implement the "bucket fill" algorithm yourself,
and copy pixels inside the polygon. That would be a lot of work, and wouldget slow done in pure Python - still, it would launch you into the basic foundations of image manipulation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Since Pygame already does the heavy lifting, but provides just solid color fills,
the way to go is to use pygame's results as a clipping mask to your texture. Unfortunatelly that is probably more difficult than it should. I hope my sample here
can be useful for others having the same needs.

Pygame gives us some primitives to manipulate the color planes in the surfaces,
but they are definitely low level. Another thing is that these primitives require
numpy to be installed - I am not certain if Window's pyagames installer include it - 
otherwise people running your project have to be told to install numpy themselves.

So, teh way to go is:
Load your desired texture in a surface (for less headache, one of the same size
of the final image), to draw the shape you want to be painted with the texture
in a mask surface, with 8bpp (B&W) - which works as a transparency map to the
texture - 
them use pygame's surfarray utilities to blit everything together:

```
# coding: utf-8

import random

import pygame

SIZE = 800,600

def tile_texture(texture, size):
    result = pygame.Surface(size, depth=32)
    for x in range(0, size[0], texture.get_width()):
        for y in range(0, size[1], texture.get_height()):
            result.blit(texture,(x,y))
    return result


def apply_alpha(texture, mask):
    """
    Image should be  a 24 or 32bit image,
    mask should be an 8 bit image with the alpha
    channel to be applied
    """
    texture = texture.convert_alpha()
    target = pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha(texture)
    target[:] = pygame.surfarray.array2d(mask)
    # surfarray objets usually lock the Surface. 
    # it is a good idea to dispose of them explicitly
    # as soon as the work is done.
    del target
    return texture

def stamp(image, texture, mask):
    image.blit(apply_alpha(texture, mask), (0,0))


def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    texture = tile_texture(pygame.image.load("texture.png"), SIZE)
    mask = pygame.Surface(SIZE, depth=8)
    # Create sample mask:
    pygame.draw.polygon(mask, 255, 
                        [(random.randrange(SIZE[0]), random.randrange(SIZE[1]) )
                         for _ in range(5)] , 0)

    stamp(screen, texture, mask)
    pygame.display.flip()
    while not any(pygame.key.get_pressed()):
        pygame.event.pump()
        pygame.time.delay(30)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    try:
        main()
    finally:
        pygame.quit()
```